# Convert 2D input array to 2D list directly using inbuilt function

Tags: python, list, input

How to convert an input 2D array to a 2D list?
For example:

> The user inputs: [[2,3], [3,4]]

This is read as a string when I read it from standard input using `input()` method. But I want it as a list of lists in python.

for eg: a = [[2,3], [3,4]]
type(a)
<class, 'list'>

Is there an inbuilt function or library for it? How to do it?
I am trying but can't resolve it.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` handles basically anything that a) looks like an **expression** in Python source code, b) doesn't require looking up any names (variables, functions, classes etc.) and c) doesn't involve any language keywords or operators. So, any kind of nested structure of *literal* data.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), consider following simple example

```
import ast
user_input = "[[2,3], [3,4]]" # str
a = ast.literal_eval(user_input)
print(isinstance(a,list))
```

output

```
True
```

`ast` is part of standard library.